# How do I enable adding comments to my Quip Live App?

Tags: liveapps, quip

I've seen comments on some Quip Live Apps both within the app itself and at the meta-level of the whole app. Can you point me to the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Adding comments is one of the more powerful features of the platform, in that it enables collaboration for your app without you having to do very much work - depending on where you want to enable commenting it involves an edit to your manifest.json as well as some work with your data model.

See:
https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/recipes#adding-quip-comments

Answer (score 0):

We tried to add native Quip comments inside the Live App.
Here some code snippets, maybe they can be useful for you:

root.jsx - Here we added three properties of CommentableRecord type to RootRecord

```
import quip from 'quip';
import App from './components/App/App.jsx';

class RootRecord extends quip.apps.RootRecord {
  static getProperties = () => ({
    commentableRecord1: CommentableRecord1,
    commentableRecord2: CommentableRecord2,
    commentableRecord3: CommentableRecord3,
  });
  static getDefaultProperties = () => ({
    commentableRecord1: {},
    commentableRecord2: {},
    commentableRecord3: {},
  })
}

quip.apps.registerClass(RootRecord, "root-record");

class CommentableRecord extends quip.apps.Record {
  static getProperties = () => ({});
  getDom = () => this.node;
  setDom = node => this.node = node;
  supportsComments = () => true;
}
class CommentableRecord1 extends CommentableRecord {}
class CommentableRecord2 extends CommentableRecord {}
class CommentableRecord3 extends CommentableRecord {}

quip.apps.registerClass(CommentableRecord1, "commentable-record-1");
quip.apps.registerClass(CommentableRecord2, "commentable-record-2");
quip.apps.registerClass(CommentableRecord3, "commentable-record-3");

quip.apps.initialize({
  initializationCallback: (rootNode) => {
    const rootRecord = quip.apps.getRootRecord();

    const commentableRecords = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) commentableRecords.push(rootRecord.get(`commentableRecord${i}`));

    ReactDOM.render(<App commentableRecords={commentableRecords} />, rootNode);
  }
});
```

App React Component - Here we rendering our comments

```
...
render = () => {
  const commentsBlock = this.props.commentableRecords.map((record, index) => (
    <div ref={c => record.setDom(c)} className={`commentableRecord${index + 1}`}>
      <quip.apps.ui.CommentsTrigger record={record} showEmpty={true}/>
    </div>
  ));

  return (
    <div className={Styles.App}>
      ...
      {commentsBlock}
    </div>
  );
}
...
```

It looks like not a good solution, but it works for us for a while :)